# How to do a triangular array in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to do something like

```
array ((0,0), (25, 25)) [((i,j), 1) | i <- [0..25], j <- [i..25]]
```

which you can see by the array index, is only defined when `i <= j`.  However, when I try to print this out in ghci I get an error because it tries to print things like `(1,0)` due to the array bounds.

```
((1,0),*** Exception: (Array.!): undefined array element
```

I could just have the array be square and put something like 0's in those entries, but I think that would be suboptimal. Is there a way I can set up the bounds of this array to be "triangular"?

Comment: `newtype Triangular a = Triangular (Array (Int, Int) a)`, write a custom `Show` instance, and make sure your code never accidentally accesses the undefined parts of the array. You won't get much help with that from the type checker, though.

Comment: Alternately, you could also define a new type of [`Ix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Ix.html) index

Comment: If you want to avoid wasting half the space you could use a 1-dimensional array and compute the index as "d i j = (i * (i-1)) `div` 2 + j".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple *upper triangular index* can be defined as:

```
import Data.Ix (Ix, range, index, inRange)

data UpperTriagIndex = Int :. Int
  deriving (Show, Ord, Eq)

instance Ix UpperTriagIndex where
  range (a :. b, c :. d) = concatMap (\i -> (i :.) <$> [max i b..d]) [a..c]
  inRange (a :. b, c :. d) (i :. j) = a <= i && i <= c && b <= j && j <= d

  index pr@(a :. b, c :. d) ix@(i :. j)
    | inRange pr ix = f a - f i + j - i
    | otherwise     = error "out of range!"
    where f x = let s = d + 1 - max x b in s * (s + 1) `div` 2
```

One can verify that `range` and `index` round trip even if the array is *not* square. For example:

```
\> let pr = (0 :. 0, 3 :. 5) in index pr <$> range pr
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]  -- [0..17]
```

and:

```
\> import Data.Array (array, (!))
\> let f i j = (i :. j, "row: " ++ show i ++ ", col: " ++ show j)
\> let a = array ((0 :. 0), (3 :. 3)) [f i j | i <- [0..3], j <- [i..3]]
\> a ! (2 :. 3)
"row: 2, col: 3"
```